# Why does the cumulative order in which nodes are first visited with Iterative deepening is effectively breadth-first

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I have had comparative algorithm exercise to do about algorithm propoerties such as completeness, time complexity, memory complexity... I discovered **Iterative deepening depth-first search algorithm**.

On Wikipedia, it is said that it visits the nodes in the search tree in the same order as depth-first search, *but the cumulative order in which nodes are first visited is effectively breadth-first*.

I know what breadth-first algorithm is but I don't understand that last sentence... What does it actually means?

Answer (score 1):

What this statement means is that if you list the order in which vertices are "discovered" (first visited) in iterative deepening DFS, then it will be the same order in which vertices are discovered in BFS.